# Proteger planilha Excel em C#

Tags: c#, microsoft-excel, windows, arquivo, csv

Em uma aplicação C#, que pode ter de 1 a 2100 horas de recolhimento de dados. Os dados são salvos em uma planilha CSV Excel a cada minuto. 
Com o código abaixo podemos esconder e mostrar o arquivo.

```
    #region
    string diret=saveFileDialog1.FileName;
    Encoding sjisX=Encoding.GetEncoding("Shift_JIS");
    StreamWriter arquivo=new StreamWriter(diret,true,sjisX);
    FileInfo fileProtec=new FileInfo(saveFileDialog1.FileName);
    fileProtec.Attributes=FileAttributes.Archive;
    arquivo.Write(tb_csv.Text);
    arquivo.Close();
    fileProtec.Attributes=FileAttributes.Hidden;
    #endregion
```

Mesmo com esta proteção é possível abrir o arquivo no Excel.
Se o arquivo estiver aberto os dados não serão salvos. 
Qual a forma esperta e inteligente de impedir que este arquivo seja aberto até terminar a colheita de dados?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Use [SpreadsheetLight](http://spreadsheetlight.com/).

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet;
using SpreadsheetLight;

namespace ConsoleApp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            SLDocument sl = new SLDocument();

            // Note that there's no password protection.
            // This just prevents the casual user from editing the
            // worksheet.

            SLSheetProtection sp = new SLSheetProtection();
            sp.AllowInsertRows = true;
            sp.AllowInsertColumns = false;
            sp.AllowFormatCells = true;
            sp.AllowDeleteColumns = true;
            sl.ProtectWorksheet(sp);

            // Use this to unprotect the currently selected worksheet.
            //sl.UnprotectWorksheet();

            // Note that this only unprotects worksheet without password protection.

            sl.SetCellValue(2, 2, "I'm protected. Sort of...");

            sl.SaveAs("WorksheetProtection.xlsx");

            Console.WriteLine("End of program");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Oi Thiago, editei a pergunta. É possivel usar SpreadsheetLight com csv?

Comment: Nossa, na vdd sua dúvida nada tem a ver com Excel. CSV não é planilha,e sim apenas um arquivo texto. Recomendo mudar a extensão para `.DAT`. Entes de iniciar o import, faça uma cópia do arquivo e leia a partir da cópia.

Comment: Vou aceitar sua resposta devido ao fato que antes de editar a pergunta, a referencia era Excel; então você respondeu. Muito agradecido.